# Viewport Confusion When You Want IPad To Display Desktop Site And Then Use Media Queries For Smaller Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, ios, css, viewport

I have read a great deal about viewport tags and understand the principles of them however I do still have some confusion over how to best use them in certain situations such as this.

So currently I am working on a site where there is a container div that is set to a width of 1024px.  To make this work on the IPad I set the following viewport tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024" />
```

All good so far.  Rotation works fine.

I then have a number of media queries to target mobile devices with a smaller screen.  I understand that the IPad is considered a mobile device.  So the site looks as I would expect BUT the viewport has to be set to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

So the two can't be combined so I would like to know how to solve this issue or what I am doing wrong?

Can you have a different viewport tag based on device width?

All time and help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with the Twitter Bootstrap framework, I'm using this so that on all tablets we see the desktop version but on all mobile phones we see the mobile version.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=false, initial-scale=1.0;">
```

Another one I had issues with were Windows Phones. They seemed to do the reverse before I had this meta tag, and show the desktop version instead of the mobile version!